# Sorting Results returned by SimpleXML, and Xpath in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, sorting

I get and display the results from the XML like so:

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    //RUN QUERY ON XML
    $xQuery = $xml->xpath($query);

foreach($xQuery as $results){
?>
        MAKE:  <?php echo $results->Make;?><br />
        Model: <?php echo $results->Model;?><br />
   <?php } ?>
```

Now what I would like to do is sort the $xQuery to for instance display the results of the Make's in alphabetical order before I display it.

Is this possible? If so how can I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do it with XPath or something, but `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` returns an array that is easy to sort:

```
usort($xQuery, function ($a, $b) { return strcmp($a->Make, $b->Make); });
foreach ($xQuery as $results) {
    // …
}
```

Comment: Looks good. I will try this and let you know how it works out for me. thank you

Comment: Hi, i receive and error when I try your suggestion:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Comment: Apparently if you are pre php5.3 you need to do it like so
function cmp ($a, $b) {
 return strcmp($a->$sort, $b->$sort);
}

usort($xQuery, "cmp");

Comment: How would I achieve the same results if the values were numerical? (descending)

Comment: If numerical, you can just use `$a['Make'] > $b['Make']` or something.